# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2) i want to solve this problem

Tags: keras

I'm spending too much time on this problem.

```
input_text, target_text, _= line.split('\t')
```

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

i delete this ',_' , another problem occurs, expected 2

why this problem happens?

Comment: You'll probably have to add more information. As far as I can guess you're trying to split lines separated by `\t` tabs, and sometimes there are two and sometimes there are three.

Comment: How does line look?

Answer (score 0):

If `line = "This\ttest"` then
`line.split('\t')` will return `["This, "test"]`, which has 2 values

If `line = "This\ttest\tagain"` then `line.split('\t')` will return `["This, "test", "again"]`, which has 3 values.

Your code: `input_text, target_text, _= line.split('\t')` expects to return 3 values which will be assigned to input_text, target_text, and _
If "line" results into list of 3 items then your code work, otherwise you are getting an error.